# Three.js with plotting software

Tags: plot, three.js

I'm trying to do some plotting on a plane i.e.

I have

floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 35, 35);

I can write text on the plane and that works fine.  However, I would really like to use a plotting toolbox like jsxgraph or similar and then use that to put the output on the plane.  I just can't see how to use jsxgraph with a canvas or similar.  Any other plotting toolboxes would be fine if I can get them to work.  Just trying to find out the options here.

Any ideas anyone?

cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0):

JSXGraph allows to choose the graphic rendering engine. Possible choices are SVG, canvas, VML (IE only), and no output. By default, JSXGraph chooses SVG if available. The graphic engine can be forced by setting it explicitely:

```
JXG.Options.renderer = 'canvas'; // or 'svg', 'vml', 'no'
var brd = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {});
```

Comment: Cheers Alfred.  That was a great help.  I finally got it to work after I figured out extracting the canvas id using "board.renderer.canvasRoot".  It's all looking great now though.  Cheers Paul.